# Changing images with dropdown but with passing specific values

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

I have some code which changes images along with the dropdown options (this part works fine):

```
<select id="picDD" class="input-sm" name="picDD">
  <option value="1">Nie wiem / obojętnie</option>
  <option value="2">"Woda"</option>
  <option value="3">"Wiatr"</option>
  <option value="4">"Ziemia"</option>
  <option value="5">"Ogień"</option>
  <option value="6">Kilka apartamentów</option>
</select>
<img id="apartament" src="images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/6.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
```

and jquery:

```
      var pictureList = [
        "0",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/1.jpg",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/2.jpg",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/3.jpg",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/4.jpg",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/5.jpg",
        "http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/6.jpg", ];

        $('#picDD').change(function () {
            var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
            $('#apartament').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
        });
```

The thing I want to change here is to change values from numbers to strings of text because I use a php script to send this choice in a form and receiving numbers, like 1,2,3,4,5,6 doesn't mean anything to me, I would prefer to have the following options as values:

```
<option value="Nie wiem">Nie wiem / obojętnie</option>
<option value="Woda">"Woda"</option>
<option value="Wiatr">"Wiatr"</option>
<option value="Ziemia">"Ziemia"</option>
<option value="Ogien">"Ogień"</option>
<option value="Kilka apartamentow">Kilka apartamentów</option>
```

How to modify the code to send text strings instead of numbers from dropdown? I'd like to modify jquery script, rather than change php. 
Thank you for help. Fiddle below:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/vmngb3rc/6/)

Comment: Are you familiar with objects?  `{ "Nie wiem": "value", "Woda": "another value" }`

Comment: I want to pass strings of text "Nie wiem" etc as a choice.

Comment: Sure.  That's what I'm saying.  If you change the values to strings, then your array just needs to change to be an object with the option values as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `change` function, you can access the selected index using the following:

```
$('#picDD').change(function () {
  var index = $(this).prop("selectedIndex");
  $('#apartament').attr("src",pictureList[index]);
});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s327mwdj/

**Edit**

**Refactor 1:** Instead of storing a hard-coded array with all the possible values, we can save ourselves some time and use `index` to construct a new image `src`. Note, I'm using ES6 Template Literals to build the new string.

**Refactor 2:** An event handler function should be created one time, outside of the event. This is more efficient than using anonymous functions because we aren't recreating the event handler function every time the `<select>` changes.

```
function buildSrcUrl(index) {
  return `http://apartamentynarie.pl/images/rezerwacje/rezerwacje-img/${index}.jpg`;
}

function handleChange() {
  $('#apartament').attr("src", buildSrcUrl(
    $(this).prop("selectedIndex")
  ));            
}

$('#picDD').on("change", handleChange);
```

Refactored Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnhsfr1q/

Comment: Thank you @AndyHoffman, any chance you can modify the jsfiddle? I'm not very good in jquery. Thank you

Comment: Amazing! thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Always keep in mind that positional based logic is inheriently fragile.  If there is ever the case that the order could change, without the array being changed to match, this logic could break.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski I updated my answer and included a link to the updated Fiddle.